# if exists overwrite with new data else create new row in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.0

I am using Ruby 2 and Rails 4. I want to create new data if the 'name' does not exist, and if it exists then update with new data. From my picture, if 'lol' exists, update new pdf file when uploading else create new row with new data. How can I do this? Please share with me if any has any idea.

[image]

My codes are:
Static_pages controller:

```
def create_form
    @form_downup = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @form_downup.save

      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to downloads_form_path
    end
  end

 private
    def contact_params
       params.require(:contact).permit(:name,:file)

    end
```

downloads_form.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <%= form_tag create_form_path,  multipart: true  do |f| %>
            <tr>                
                <td class=""><%= text_field_tag "contact[name]", nil, class: "form-control" %></td>
                <td><%= file_field_tag "contact[file]",  class: "form-control" %></td>
                <td><%= submit_tag 'Upload' %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Download", static_pages_downloadform_pdf_path(:file_name => "lol") %></td>

            </tr>

                <% end %> 

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by).

```
def create_form
    @form_downup = Contact.find_or_initialize_by(name: params[:contact][:name])
    @form_downup.file = params[:contact][:file]
    if @form_downup.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to downloads_form_path
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this looks a bit ugly, but it should do the trick

```
def create_form
  contact = Contact.find_or_initialize_by(name: params[:contact][:name])
  contact.file = params[:contact][:file]

  if contact.save
    redirect_to :back
  else
    redirect_to downloads_form_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

```
@form_downup = Contact.find_or_create_by(:name => contact_params[:name])   
@form_downup.file=contact_params[:file]
@form_downup.save
```